# configure: error: iconv does not support errno

Tags: php, macos-catalina

i have problem when installing php 8.2 in MacOS Catalina, Macbook Pro 2015.

```
==> Patching
==> ./buildconf --force
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.5 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/8.2 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/8.2 --with-config-
Last 15 lines from /Users/aidan/Library/Logs/Homebrew/php/02.configure:
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset in -lintl... yes
checking for GNU MP support... yes
checking for __gmpz_rootrem in -lgmp... yes
checking for mhash support... yes
checking size of long... (cached) 8
checking if we're at 64-bit platform... yes
checking for iconv support... yes
checking for libiconv in -liconv... no
checking for iconv in -liconv... yes
checking if iconv is glibc's... no
checking if using GNU libiconv... no
checking if iconv is Konstantin Chuguev's... no
checking if using IBM iconv... no
checking if iconv supports errno... no
configure: error: iconv does not support errno

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!
```

configure: error: iconv does not support errno

i have installed libiconv in my mb.

thank you for your solution.

Comment: Which implementation/version of libiconv have you installed in your mb?

Comment: iconv (GNU libiconv 1.17)

Comment: You should find out exactly where did you install libiconv and use option `--with-iconv=path` when running configure, e.g. `--with-iconv=/usr/local`